# How do I fix the multiple commands produce error on Xcode (11.4)

Tags: xcode

I was trying to connect Firebase and after importing the info.pList file, I got this error:

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-cprwjjarcsfhrsbrbdfvepabszpu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app/Info.plist':
1) Target 'app' (projectapp') has copy command from '/Users/user/Desktop/app/app/Info.plist' to '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-cprwjjarcsfhrsbrbdfvepabszpu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app/Info.plist'
2) Target ' app' (project 'app') has process command with output '/Users/usr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-cprwjjarcsfhrsbrbdfvepabszpu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app/Info.plist'
```

Answer (score 5):

Open **Info.plist** file in Xcode, open file inspector and check for **Target Membership** for your app.

[image]

This option must be **unchecked**, if it's checked, please uncheck and build again.

Comment: Select your app target under **TARGETS** in the project, Go to **Build Settings**, search for **Info.plist** and make sure this path value and the path at which **Info.plist** is present in Finder matches.

Comment: I'm not sure I can check if the path values are same or how I can edit them, I am pretty new to this. I've updated the question and put  a screenshot of the build setting

Comment: Where it says **Multiple Values**, double tap that area and paste following `$(SRCROOT)/Bakery app/Info.plist` and then try building.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried various suggestions and none seem to work, here’s a method that has worked for me :)

**1. Delete the 'Pods' Directory:**

Run the command `rm -rf Pods` in your terminal. This will remove the 'Pods' directory and all its contents.

**2. Delete the 'Podfile.lock' File:**

Use the command `rm Podfile.lock` to delete the 'Podfile.lock' file. This file locks your project to specific versions of the Pods.

**3. Delete the 'node_modules' Directory:**

Execute `rm -rf node_modules` to remove the 'node_modules' directory. This directory contains all the npm packages.

**4. Delete the 'package-lock.json' File:**

Remove the 'package-lock.json' file by running `rm package-lock.json`. This file locks your npm dependencies to specific versions.

**5. Reinstall npm Packages:**

After deleting the necessary files and directories, run `npm install`. This command will reinstall the npm packages based on your 'package.json' file.

**6. Clean the CocoaPods Cache:**

Perform a cache clean for CocoaPods using `pod cache clean --all`. This will clear any stored CocoaPods artifacts.

**7. Install Pods:**

Finally, run `pod install` to install the CocoaPods dependencies.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the issues you're facing with your project. Remember, this is specifically useful for projects that use both CocoaPods and npm.