# Xcode 15.2 encountered an archival failure, despite the code executing successfully on the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Objective-C codebase that is six years old. I recently made some modifications to the code, and it runs successfully on the simulator. However, when attempting to create an archive, I encountered an error indicating:

```
"Multiple commands produce '/Users/karamjeet.singh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HP_xxx-bfrshadjilbcluewhoduspxudcoa/ArchiveIntermediates/PayxxxPrint/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/include.'"
```

Comment: Go to Select Targets -> BuildPhases . This could be because of having multiple files with the same names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71004189/multiple-commands-produce-error-in-xcode-13, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69476019/multiple-commands-produce, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805402/how-do-i-fix-the-multiple-commands-produce-error-on-xcode-11-4.

Comment: @AshwaniKumar I tried all the solution which are I come across the stack-over flow.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone!

I managed to resolve the issue by relocating the file from "Build Phase" -> "Headers" -> "From Public" to "Project" within one of my directly added framework projects in the codebase. Since I didn't originally create this project from scratch and I'm just addressing some issues in code that's eight years old, I wasn't certain about whether the file needed to be in the public or project section.